# when click list item, open new SwiftUI for every list items in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI project, when I click the any list items, I want to route new view. Below, I try to use it for settings and notifications list items, but it throw error,I do not know why? I search on internet, but did not find any solution to help me.  Any idea?

**ContentView:**

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
 NavigationView {
  List(contacts) { contact in
    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView(contact: contact)) {
      ContactRow(contact: contact)
    }
  }
  .navigationBarTitle("Contacts")
 }
 .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
}
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
ContentView()
 }
}
 struct ContactRow: View {

 let contact: Settings

 var body: some View {
   HStack {
  Image(contact.imageName)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    
     
  VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text(contact.name)
      .font(.system(size: 21, weight: .medium, design: .default))
    }}}}
```

**Settings.swift:**

```
import SwiftUI
struct Settings: Identifiable {
let imageName: String
 let name: String
let id = UUID()
}
let contacts = [
Settings(imageName: "settings", name: "Settings"),
Settings(imageName: "notifications", name: "Notifications"),
]
```

**SettingsView:**

```
struct SettingsView: View {

let contact: Settings

var body: some View {
  Text("hey")
}
}
struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    SettingsView(contact: contacts[0])
       }}
```

**NotificationsView:**

```
struct NotificationsView: View {

let contact: Settings

var body: some View {
  Text("hey")
}
}
struct NotificationsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    NotificationsView(contact: contacts[1])
       }}
```

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: @Asperi, it is not work.

Comment: @Asperi it is jump always same view, I want to jump new view, when I click the the new item

Comment: What do you mean “it jumps to same view”? It stays on your view with the list?

Comment: Or does it jump to the view that says “Hey”. And you want something different?

Comment: @rlong405 I mean when u click any list items, open own view. for example when I click the settings list item, it can be open settings view....

Comment: Ok and what’s currently happening when you click on a list item?

Comment: @when I click any items, all of them route same view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well how works NavigationView, instead i prefer use a View Router as env object to navigate.

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
@ObservedObject var vm:RecordingsModelView

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30, content: {
        
        Text("Recordings").font(.title).foregroundColor(Color("color_ekp"))
        
        List(vm.listOfRecordings) { recording in
            RecordingRow(recording: recording).onTapGesture {
                viewRouter.currentRecording = recording
                viewRouter.currentPage = .rec_detail
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            vm.loadRecordings()
        }
    }).padding()
}
```

The ViewRouter

```
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var currentPage: Page = .recordings
    
    // Custom
    @Published var currentRecording: RecordingEntity!
}
```

And a root view to show the page selected

```
struct RootView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        switch viewRouter.currentPage {
        case .main:
            MainView()
        case .recordings:
            RecordingsView()
        case .rec_detail:
            RecDetailView(recording: viewRouter.currentRecording)
        }
    }
}
```

I also take the opportunity to pass an object to the next page, in this case the recoding selection from a list of recordings.

Comment: how can I impelement it to my question, tnx for answer

Comment: With the ViewRouter and the RootView that i suggested you don't need to use NavigationView and you can navigate to the view desired from any part of code.
Nesting navigation views doesn't seem easy to handle.